# C# Nunit and Running same database populate everytime before test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, nunit

I have an Entity Framework DB Context file.
How would I setup the DBContext, and run SetUp everytime (to have clean populated database) before running a test? It cannot see the dbcontext in the NUnit tests.

**Electronics DB Context file**

```
public partial class ElectronicsContext : DbContext
{
    public ElectronicsContext()
    {
    }

    public ElectronicsContext(DbContextOptions<ElectronicsContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategory { get; set; }
```

**Nunit SetUp**

```
public class TestClass
{

    [SetUp]
    public void TestProducts()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Products Test")
            .Options;

        using (var context = new ElectronicsContext(options))
        {
            context.Product.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, ProductName = "TV", ProductDescription = "TV testing", ImageLocation = "test" , ProductCategoryId = 2});
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**Error Message here**

```
The name 'context' does not exist in the current context    

    [Test]
    public void TestProductRepository()
    {
        ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository(context);
        Assert.AreEqual("TV", productRepository.GetById(1).ProductName);
    }
}
```

Alternative Idea for SetUp was not working either:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void TestProducts()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Products Test")
            .Options;

        ElectronicsContext context = new ElectronicsContext(options);
```

Comment: Although two people have already answered, it's actually not possible to give a good answer to your question without knowing the version of NUnit you are using, at least whether it's V2 or V3. :-( I could write two answers, but I'm lazy. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create private member of test class, which can be instantiated in `SetUp` method and used in the test methods.

Because NUnit will create instance of TestClass once for all tests in the class, you can not use `readonly` member.
Context should be re-assigned (reset) for every test to keep them isolated from each other.

```
public class TestClass
{
    private DbContext _context;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var options = 
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ElectronicsContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Products Test")
                .Options;

        // new instance of ElectronicsContext will be created for every test.
        _context = new ElectronicsContext(options);

        // Use _context to insert initial data required for the test

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }

    [Test]
    public void RunTest()
    {
        // run test
        // assert
        _context.Products.Count().Should().Be(10)
    }
}
```

Imagine that test fixture is just a c# class which methods marked with `Test` attribute executed sequentially.

```
var test = new TestClass();
// first test
test.SetUp();    // create db context
test.RunTest();  // use db context
test.TearDown(); // dispose db context

// second test
test.SetUp();       // create db context
test.RunTest_Two(); // use db context
test.TearDown();    // dispose db context
```